# Nginx HTTPS when only matching admin subfolder

Tags: regex, https, nginx

I have managed to get all /admin requests redirected to https by:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /admin {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
}
```

But can't figure out how to get all https requests that are not within /admin redirected to http, so far I have:

```
server {
    listen       443;

    location ~ /admin {
        rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have got the redirects working as required but can't stop the /admin url going to 404. It feels like I need to put something in the empty block.

```
server {
    listen       443;

    location /admin {

    }   

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this may answer my question http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location. "there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead, match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then use location / to match anything else."

Comment: Please do not cross post – your question will be migrated  to a better site if it's off topic somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow serve something when `/admin` is loaded. So decide what you want to be served.

For instance:

```
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

will serve static files in that directory. Add whatever you need.